# GCC can't vectorize this simple loop ('number of iterations cannot be computed') yet managed a similar one in the same code?

Tags: c++, gcc, vectorization

So, I have C++ code with this loop:

```c
for(i=0;i<(m-1);i++)    N4[i]=(i+m-1-Rigta[i]-1-N3[i])/N0;
```

All the quantitiy involved are `int`'s. From GCC's vectorization report I get:

```
babar.cpp:233: note: ===== analyze_loop_nest =====
babar.cpp:233: note: === vect_analyze_loop_form ===
babar.cpp:233: note: === get_loop_niters ===
babar.cpp:233: note: not vectorized: number of iterations cannot be computed.
babar.cpp:233: note: bad loop form.
```

I wondering why 'the number of iteration cannot be computed'!? FWIW, `m` is declared as
`const int& m`. What makes this even more puzzling is that just above in the same code I have:

```c
for(i=1;i<(m-1);i++)    a2[i]=(x[i]+x[i+m-1])*0.5f;
```

and the loop above gets vectorized just fine (here `a2` and `x` are `floats`). I'm compiling with the

```
-Ofast -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=10 -mtune=native -march=native
```

flags on GCC 4.8.1 on a i7.

Thanks in advance,

## Edit:

After @nodakai idea, I tried this:

```c
const int mm = m;
for(i=0;i<(m-1);i++)    N4[i]=(i+m-1-Rigta[i]-1-N3[i])/N0;
```

this didn't get me quiet there:

```
babar.cpp:234: note: not vectorized: relevant stmt not supported: D.55255_812 = D.55254_811 / N0_34;
babar.cpp:234: note: bad operation or unsupported loop bound.
```

so of course, I tried:

```c
const int mm=m;
const float G0=1.0f/(float)N0;
for(i=0;i<(mm-1);i++)   N4[i]=(i+mm-1-Rigta[i]-1-N3[i])*G0;
```

which then produced:

```
babar.cpp:235: note: LOOP VECTORIZED.
```

(e.g. success). Oddly enough, the `mm` seems necessary(?!).

Comment: const int& m means it's referencing something you can't change, not something that can't change..

Comment: @AurélienOoms: thanks for the comment. So, how can I help 'him' understand that m is fixed to the length of N4.

Comment: `const int m = compile_time_constant;` otherwise I think it won't work

Comment: Where do you get the reference from?

Comment: @AurélienOoms: I added more details to the questions (it wouldn't fit in a comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try these two steps and see if there's any differences?

1. insert `const int mm = m;` just before the loop.
2. replace all the occurences of `m` with `mm`.

Comment: it worked (thanks!). But please can you explain why?

Comment: The semantics around reference (and pointer) is sometimes confusing! The problem is, `const int &` is a "read-only" reference to a (potentially) mutable loop boundary.  That's why GCC isn't confident enough that the loop bound will not change within the loop if you use `const int &m`.  See the sample code here http://ideone.com/LRGold

Comment: OK. Thanks for the explanation ans the answer, it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop bounds probably do not divide by the vectorization factor.  Note that in the loop that vectorizes, the loop iterates for one less time than the one that does not.  As a simple test to see if this is the case, you can change the starting point of your non-vectorized loop to `1` and then do the `0` case prior to the loop, like:

```c
N4[0] = (m - 1 - Rigta[0] - 1 - N3[0]) / N0;
for(i=1; i<(m-1); i++) {
    N4[i]=(i + m - 1 - Rigta[i] - 1 - N3[i])/N0;
}
```

Comment: thanks (it was a good suggestion!), but it didn't work:( (same  message as above).